# Pandas - Averaging entries in specific row and column

Tags: python, pandas

I've imported an excel sheet which has a series of tables. The pandas dataframe looks like this:

```
   1   2   3   4    
0  3   2   7   2   
1  4   2   8   1
2  5   1   4   1
3  6   0   2   3
NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
   1   2   3   4  
0  3   2   2   1
1  3   3   9   1
2  3   1   5   1
3  2   9   4   1

......
```

I'd like to average all values in each respective cell (ie. average values in row 0, column 1 of each table) resulting in 1 table which contains all the averages.

I'm not sure how to alter the `df.groupby(['1']).mean()` function in order to isolate the cells by row as well. I can use a loop to iterate through columns, but it may be tricky to do that and iterate through the rows simultaneously. I'd appreciate any suggestions.

Desired output:

```
   1   2   3    4    
0  3   2   4.5  1.5   
1  3.5 2.5 8.5  1
2  4   1   4.5  1
3  4   4.5 3    2
```

Comment: can you please add an example of the desired output?

Comment: @DeanTaler - sure I added one - it's basically a table of averages.

Comment: Do you need `df.groupby(level=0).mean()` ? What is `print (df.info())` ?

Comment: There are same columns names in each DataFrame?

Comment: @jezrael - yes, each table has the same column names and is separated by some strings which are imported as NaN

Comment: So need `df.groupby(level=0).mean()` ? Working well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If first column is index and same columns names in each subDataFrame simpliest is:

```
print (df)
       1    2    3    4
0.0  3.0  2.0  7.0  2.0
1.0  4.0  2.0  8.0  1.0
2.0  5.0  1.0  4.0  1.0
3.0  6.0  0.0  2.0  3.0
NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
NaN  1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0
0.0  3.0  2.0  2.0  1.0
1.0  3.0  3.0  9.0  1.0
2.0  3.0  1.0  5.0  1.0
3.0  2.0  9.0  4.0  1.0


df = df.groupby(level=0).mean()
print (df)
       1    2    3    4
0.0  3.0  2.0  4.5  1.5
1.0  3.5  2.5  8.5  1.0
2.0  4.0  1.0  4.5  1.0
3.0  4.0  4.5  3.0  2.0
```

If not, is necessary some preprocessing, depends of data.

E.g. remove rows if last column has `NaN`s for avoid mixed row=1 with indexes=1:

```
print (df)
       1    2    3    4
0.0  3.0  2.0  7.0  2.0
1.0  4.0  2.0  8.0  1.0
2.0  5.0  1.0  4.0  1.0
3.0  6.0  0.0  2.0  3.0
NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  NaN <- columns names like index=1 here are removed
0.0  3.0  2.0  2.0  1.0
1.0  3.0  3.0  9.0  1.0
2.0  3.0  1.0  5.0  1.0
3.0  2.0  9.0  4.0  1.0


df = df.dropna(subset=df.columns[-1:]).groupby(level=0).mean()
print (df)
       1    2    3    4
0.0  3.0  2.0  4.5  1.5
1.0  3.5  2.5  8.5  1.0
2.0  4.0  1.0  4.5  1.0
3.0  4.0  4.5  3.0  2.0
```